# Derivates of function and limits

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, limits, derivatives

I wonder if it's true $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{d}{dx}f_n(x)=\frac{d}{dx} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)$$
When $\displaystyle f_n(x)$ is a sequence of function.

Comment: The limit might not even be differentiable.

Comment: The limit might not even exist, take $f_n=n$

Answer (score 3):

It is true on $[a, b]$ and it's a consequence of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, provided

(1) the sequence of derivatives $f_n'$ converges UNIFORMLY to some $g$

(2) the sequence $f_n(x)$ converges for at least one $x$ (which under (1) is enough to enforce that $f_n$ converge uniformly to some $f$ with $f'=g$)

and it is very very false if one of these is not satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following counter-example.

Let $$f_n(x) = \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

It is clear that $f_n(x) \to 0$ point-wise. Ergo, the derivative of the limit is $0$. But, consider

$$f^{'}_n = \sqrt{n} \cos(nx)$$  the limit of this sequences does not even exist!